# iOS local host RTMP server

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, server, vlc, rtmp

I have been tasked with creating an iPad application, iOS 12.3 latest support, to run as a local RTMP server.  Purpose being, external devices connect to this local RTMP server on iOS iPad, either via the iPad's wifi connection or enabled hotspot, and playback the display of external devices (mirror) onto the iPad.

I have been successful with creating a local host HTTP server, but upon connecting with external devices the local server on the iPad quits.

I will be using open source software for decoding and playback of video feed such as vlc or ffmpeg, but need guidance on an iPhone local host implementation, such as https://github.com/sallar/mac-local-rtmp-server for a mac.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out